# Deploying RoR App on Shared Host fails due to Ruby version error on Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby On Rails App on a shared host, that has ruby 1.9.3-p551. Phusion Passenger now returns the error message:

```
Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.1 or newer.

    You're running
       ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]

     Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue.

  (SystemExit)
  /.../my_home_directory/.../vendor/cache/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/ruby_version_check.rb:12:in `abort'
```

and then a big stack trace.  I'm using rbenv for controlling different ruby versions. When I type in `rbenv versions` it says:

```
   system
*  1.9.3-p551 (set by /my_home_directory/.rbenv/version)
```

`ruby -v`

```
1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
```

But in the error message of passenger there's the information:

```
General Interpreter Information
RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.2
```

I can't check the Apache config files because I'm on a shared host and have therefore no root rights. So I can't reinstall ruby or rubygems.

I already tried reinstalling every local gem. I typed `bundle install` and `bundle upgrade` multiple times. I tried to install a local ruby version with `rbenv local 1.9.3-p551` in the home directory, the .rbenv directory, the app home and the app/public directory. I tried to change the used ruby version with `rbenv shell 1.9.3-p551`, and probably did some more things, I currently can't remember because I started very late to write the things down that I already did.

Why does passenger have the wrong ruby versions besides that PassengerRuby in the Apache config file is wrong? I think that's very unlikely, because I think that my hosting provider knows what he's doing. Is there something I could do to let passenger or rails use the right (installed) version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody have an idea why passenger has the wrong ruby versions besides that PassengerRuby in the Apache config file is wrong?

Passenger author here. The fact that PassengerRuby in the config file is wrong, is the *only* reason why you're having this problem. The *only* solution is to set PassengerRuby to the right instance.

If your shared host doesn't allow you to set PassengerRuby, then I recommend that you switch to a different. Try Digital Ocean for example. They're cheap, gives you full control, and we have a [full end-to-end deployment walkthrough for Digital Ocean](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/).

Comment: I found a way to change it. Actually, I don't really like the way most people advertise Digital Ocean or some different popular provider. Might be, it's really good, but if I asked a question like "Whats a good hosting provider for deployment of a Ruby on Rails App?" it would definitely be closed as "off topic". So the answer is really off topic itself. But this is going to be the best answer because the first part was the thing I wanted to know. Thanks, and don't be mad please. As already said: The first part was helpful.

Comment: I don't mean to "advertise" Digital Ocean specifically. Just about *any* hosting provider that gives you full access to the system will do. It's just that shared hosters are in general pretty horrible.